# how can i bound probability of difference between true mean difference and sample mean difference?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$$
P(||\bar{X}-\mu| - |X-\mu|| < ?) < ?
$$

Here, $X$ is a random variable, $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean of $X$. And $\mu$ is the true mean.

How can i bound the difference of differences ?

Comment: I think i just figured out $|\bar{X}-\mu| \le |X-\mu| $

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to reverse one of the inequalities, since you probably want the probability of "difference is small" to be large.

One way is
$$P(||\bar{X} - \mu| - |X - \mu|| > t)
\le P(|\bar{X} - \mu| > t/2, \ |X - \mu| > t/2)$$
If $\bar{X}$ and $X$ are independent, you can then write the right-hand side as the product of two probabilities, each of which can be bounded using whatever assumptions you have on $X$.

Comment: sorry, i don't need probability for this one. As $|x+y| \le |x| + |y| $